# MySql query to select rows with the next lower or higher date

Tags: mysql-5.1

Let' say I selected those data from a table which have the biggest date value like this:

```
SELECT * FROM  table_name WHERE column_name IN  (SELECT  MIN(column_name) FROM table_name
```

It works fine, it selects those data with the "newest" date value.

What I want to know if is there a query in MySQL to list out those data which have the next descending  date.
For example, in my first select, I've selected those rows which have the MIN date value like this: 2012-08-27 10:15:00
What I want with another query to select those data wich date value is the closest next value like this: 2012-08-28 11:45:00

So there are other rows with bigger or lower date value, but I don't want to select them. Only the closest next, from what I'm currently on.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a value for the datetime *whose* closest next element you want to find (let's name it  **comparison_date**), you could try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM  table_name WHERE column_name IN  (SELECT  MIN(column_name) FROM table_name WHERE column_name > comparison_date ORDER BY column_name)
```

This will return all the datetime values later than that date. If you want to limit it to a single result, you should use:

```
SELECT * FROM  table_name WHERE column_name IN  (SELECT  MIN(column_name) FROM table_name WHERE column_name > comparison_date ORDER BY column_name) LIMIT 1
```

Alternatively, if you want the next closest datetime from current time, you can replace **comparison_date**  with **NOW()** which is a MySQL function. Then, you can try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM  table_name WHERE column_name IN  (SELECT  MIN(column_name) FROM table_name WHERE column_name > NOW() ORDER BY column_name)
```

In order to find the next lower datetime (or previous datetime, however we call it), you should use:

```
SELECT * FROM  table_name WHERE column_name IN  (SELECT  MIN(column_name) FROM table_name WHERE column_name < comparison_date ORDER BY column_name DESC) LIMIT 1
```